# how to specify cname in eb deploy for aws

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to deploy an application revision to an existing aws instance using eb deploy, and I've spent several days browsing Amazon's documentation as well as well as related web articles including stack overflow questions and answers, to no avail. The problem is that I can't figure out how to specify the cname to which the application should be deployed. I'm a newbie so any help will be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Who is your domain provider? You need to add the CNAME mapping from the providers DNS tools. E.g map xyz.com to automatically created Elastic Beanstalk url

Answer (score 0):

Your elastic beanstalk environment, where you deployed your revision has a url assigned to it. You can check it in AWS console, or querying your environment in AWS CLI. If you have one instance only, this url will point to your instance. If you have more than one instance in your environment the url will point to your environment elastic load balancer. It does'n matter. In each case, the url will be the same.

Create an CNAME record to point to elastic beanstalk environment url. It will work fine. Even better, if you use the AWS route53 service you can create an Alias record that has some advantages if all your services are across AWS environment.

Comment: Thanks Gustavo, but I don't need to drive traffic to the site. The problem that I'm having is that eb deploy is deploying to the wrong account. I've even modified the config file to add a second profile with the appropriate credentials, and it still tries to deploy to the wrong account. Any help you can give will be greatly appreciated